# Location Updates gets stopped after 17 - 18 minutes while running in background

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

didUpdateLocations is not being called after 17 - 18 minutes of running app perfectly in background. I've checked Location Updates option to make app run in background. App runs for 15 - 20 minutes then didUpdateLocation stops being called in background.

Please help

Comment: I found the solution, we have to set pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically property to NO

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for posting the solution. In Swift 3, I set pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false and it seems to be working very well.

```
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
```